# ns3 installation error

Tags: networking, command-line, mount, compiling, paths

```
NS3_MODULE_PATH = ['/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/games', '/usr/local/games', '/usr/lib/wsl/lib', '/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath', '/mnt/c/Windows/system32', '/mnt/c/Windows', '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem', '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/', '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/', '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common', '/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR', '/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32', '/mnt/c/WINDOWS', '/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem', '/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/', '/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/', '/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-19/bin', '/mnt/c/Users/Ayaan's/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps', '/mnt/c/Users/Ayaan's/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin', '/mnt/c/flutter/bin', '/snap/bin', '/home/ayaan/workspace/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37/build', '/home/ayaan/workspace/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37/build/lib']
```

[image]

[image]

I think the problem is due to the name of my path because it has a special character. It think it's "Ayaan's" that is causing some problems.

Comment: If you don't *need* Windows components in your PATH, you can configure WSL to not append them. See [Interop settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop-settings).

Comment: I am very new at this can you help me a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely correct - the issue is the unbalanced single quote in the `NS3_MODULE_PATH` component:

```
... , '/mnt/c/Users/Ayaan's/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps', ...
```

**Assuming that**:

1. your `NS3_MODULE_PATH` is based on the `PATH` environment variable (e.g. via `os.path`); and
2. you don't really need your `PATH` to include Windows directories

Then probably the simplest fix is to configure WSL not to append the Windows path to your Ubuntu `PATH` variable. You can do so in WSL1 by creating the following minimal `/etc/wsl.conf` file (e.g. with `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`):

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

You will need to restart the WSL instance for the changes to take effect - you may find (as I did) that simply closing the WSL window is insufficient to do that, in which case you will need to use `wsl --terminate` from a Windows PowerShell or cmd.exe prompt:

```
> wsl --list --running
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)

> wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04

> wsl --list --running
There are no running distributions.
```

See for example [Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconf).

If you **do** need the Windows path to be appended, then you will need to modify how you derive `NS3_MODULE_PATH` from it in order to exclude the troublesome component(s).

Comment: thank you so much it worked